# Kafka Consumer Assignment returns Empty Set

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I  have subscribed to a Kafka topic  as below. I need to run some logic only after the consumer has been assigned a partition.

However `consumer.assignment()` comes back as an empty set no matter  how long I wait. If I do not have the while loop and then do a  `consumer.poll()` I do get the records from the topic.Can any one tell me why this is  happening ?

```java
    consumer.subscribe(topics);
    Set<TopicPartition> assigned=Collections.emptySet();
    while(isAssigned) {
          assigned = consumer.assignment();
          if(!assigned.isEmpty()) {
              isAssigned= false;
          }
    }

//consumer props
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "xxx:9092,yyy:9092");
        props.put("group.id", groupId);
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
        props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer");
        props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://xxx:8081");
        props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put("max.poll.records", "100");
```

Comment: Could you add consumer properties, that you are using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Until you call `poll()`, the consumer is just idling.

Only after `poll()` is invoked, it will initiate a connection to the cluster, get assigned partitions and attempt to fetch messages.

This is mentioned in the [Javadoc](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html):

> After subscribing to a set of topics, the consumer will automatically
>   join the group when poll(Duration) is invoked.

Once you start calling `poll()`, you can use `assignment()` or even register a [`ConsumerRebalanceListener`](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#subscribe-java.util.Collection-org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRebalanceListener-) to be notify when partitions are assigned or revoked from your consumer instance.

Comment: Just in case this helps anyone else: You might randomly get assigned without calling poll but it's rare. This can be very confusing if you didn't know poll is needed.

Comment: I am not going to lose a message in that way? Let's imagine you want to access to the partitions list calling .assignement() in order to reposition the offset.